# Performance problems on BigQuery project: Resource exceeded

Tags: google-bigquery

Suddenly we see performance issues with our project lately: `aerobic-forge-504`

```
  job_NKHejDJbT1Qn3Z3ILJEP9c78MXc   query      FAILURE   14 Jul 10:12:11   0:18:52
  job_qtv2MFOtIKZDzaNHTbXrCOt3THI   query      SUCCESS   14 Jul 10:10:32   0:21:48
  job_8eKvSGQRKe5oX6VbJHb4kpM7KVg   query      SUCCESS   14 Jul 09:41:09   0:14:53
  job_EeuvmSSHMa3BKJTeKYJ0oB33bLM   query      SUCCESS   14 Jul 09:00:51   0:15:09
```

Usually the response time is around 30 seconds, but now the queries take 15 minutes, and we didn't modified the queries for months.

We got also:  Resources exceeded during query execution

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Folks that respond to google-bigquery understand this question as they can investigate based on job ID, and resource exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the heads up. We believe this is a performance problem in our query planner, and we're working on a fix. We'll track the issue in the bug you filed over here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=283